# firebase performance returning 'Did not receive a HTTP Response Code'

Tags: android, firebase-performance

I have integrated firebase, The logs are showing in firebase console perfectly.

```
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.0.0'
```

is the snippet with firebase SDK integration . the error message is the following,

```
 03-07 13:27:05.031 I/FirebasePerformance(17999): Did not receive a HTTP 
 Response Code
 03-07 13:27:05.031 I/FirebasePerformance(17999): Unable to process an HTTP 
 request/response due to missing or invalid values. See earlier log 
 statements for additional information on the specific invalid/missing values.
```

Comment: Are you using any proxy or firewall?

Comment: no, not using any proxy or firewall

Comment: I think the only way you're going to get help here is if you show a MCVE with the exact request that you're making that reproduces this reliably.  Your app could have any number of HTTP requests that are being instrumented, and we'd have no way of knowing which one doesn't work.

Comment: @apcdgworks I have same problem, i've just added FirebasePerformance sdk version :19.0.7 and i have same errors, did you find any solution about that?